# Solve a second order linear homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2y^{"}-12y = 0, x > 0$$

Find two distinct values for $r$ so that $y=x^r$ solves the above differential equation.

I know how to solve a second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients. But for the question above, how should I deal with the $x^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Euler-Cauchy type equation, so we choose:

$$y = x^r$$

Substituting back into the ODE yields:

$$x^2y'' - 12 y = x^2 (r)(r-1)x^{r-2} -12x^r=0 \rightarrow (r(r-1) - 12)x^r = 0$$

So we have:

$$r^2 - r - 12 = 0 \rightarrow r_{1,2} = -3, 4$$

This gives us the two solutions:

- $y_1 = \dfrac{c_1}{x^3}$
- $y_2 = c_2x^4$
- Note: Verify that each of these satisfies the original ODE, and so will a linear combination.

So, our final solution is:

$$y(x) = y_1(x) + y_2(x) = \dfrac{c_1}{x^3} + c_2 x^4$$

Comment: A little typo in the second solution.

Comment: Oops - thanks! :-)

Comment: Right up your alley! +1