# How to solve a homogeneous 2nd order linear DE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this ODE:

*Given $y=x^2$ is a solution to $x^2y''+2xy'-6y=0$ find the general solution:*

The answer for the general solution is: $y=Ax^2+B/x^3$

What method do I need to employ to solve this? If it had constant coefficients instead of variables of x I could just treat it as a quadratic, find the roots and then write the appropriate general solution.

What am I supposed to do in this case and what is the name of the method used to solve such an ODE (if any)? e.g. reduction of order etc.

Also, can a full solution be found by hand if it was **nonhomogeneous**?

For $x^2y''+2xy'-6y=10x$ can I still use variation of parameters or method of undetermined coefficients to solve for the particular solution?

Please help me, I'm melting. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a general procedure called *reduction of order*; it supposes that we can write a second solution as a multiple of the first, so that

$$y_2 = x^2 v$$

for a particular function $v$. The reason we do this is that

$$y_2' = x^2 v' + 2x v \quad y_2'' = x^2 v'' + 4x v' + 2v$$

Substituting this into the original equation yields

\begin{align*}
0 &= x^2(x^2 v'' + 4xv' + 2v) + 2x (x^2 v' + 2x v) -6 x^2 v \\
&= x^4 v'' + 4x^3 v' + 2x^2 v + 2x^3 v' + 4x^2 v - 6x^2 v \\
&= x^4 v'' + 6x^3 v'
\end{align*}

Now this leads to the essentially first order equation

$$v'' = -\frac{6}{x} v'$$

which can be solved by any number of techniques, e.g. separation of variables. In general, the technique of writing $y_2 = v y_1$ for a suitable function $v$ can be used rather often to carry this procedure out.

---

If the equation is non-homogeneous, then yes: You can find the equations to the homogeneous equation via these techniques, and then solve the non-homogeneous equation via undetermined coefficients, variation of parameters, or whatever method you please.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding non-homogeneous cases. Also, is reduction of order the 'safest' method to solve these general solution problems (with no constant coefficients)?
I just looked at another question which had a similar problem:[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509528/solve-a-second-order-linear-homogeneous-ode?rq=1)
The answer in that question substituted $y=x^r$. Using that same method I managed to get the roots $r=-3$ and $r=2$ and thus the general solution. It seemed a lot easier so I'm guessing there is some horrible catch or limitation to this alternative?

Comment: @user155876 In a case when the decrease in powers of $x$ exactly matches the decrease in the number of derivatives, it's reasonable to expect that pure power functions will be the solutions; the problem is that that method is not terribly general. If you know, rather, that $e^x$ (or a related function) were a solution, then you can't apply that method - but this one might still work.

Answer (score 0):

For $x = e^z$, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}.\frac{dz}{dx}=e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz}$$

Now $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{dy}{dx}).e^{-z}=e^{-z}\frac{d}{dz}(e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz})=e^{-z}(e^{-z}\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-e^{-z}\frac{dy}{dz})=e^{-2z}(\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{dy}{dz})$$

Substituting this in your original equation, we will get :$$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{dy}{dz}+2\frac{dy}{dz}-6y=0$$.

Now this is a equation with constant coefficients and you know how to solve it.

NOw for $$x^2y''+2xy'-6y=10x$$, the new equation becomes $$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+\frac{dy}{dz}-6y=10e^z$$ which is also solvable by method of undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters